# Orientation issue while adding new activity indicator

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm updating my portrait mode iPad app to support orientation in portrait and landscape mode.

The problem is that when I add an activity indicator view in portrait mode and then change the orientation to landscape, the indicator view remains in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this code line:

```
[yourActivityIndicatorView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

This will make your activity indicator always in the middle of the screen.